# HTML buttons will only work only on webpage re/-load

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT :** Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. I appreciate the tips guys.

I changed my `window.onload`and inserted the two event listeners inside of it.
After that I took the idea of @Ito Pizarro , and implemented it in my own way.

The result looks like this :

```
function openDoor() {
var x_1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var x_2 = document.getElementById('img2');
is_visible = (x_1.style.visibility == "hidden");

if (is_visible) {
    x_1.style.visibility = "visible";
}
else {
    x_2.style.visibility = "hidden";
}}
```

And I also did the same for my `closeDoor()` function.
**END OF EDIT**

I create a HTML page, with two buttons. Every button has its purpose when it's being clicked. The first one will show an image of an opened door. The second button will show an image of a close door. When the page is loaded no image is being shown. They appear only if their button is clicked.

Tried to created a nested if-statement with the a global bool that will make it run infinitely.

Also tried a for & while loop.

But I am new to programming and I struggle a bit.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('OpenDoor').addEventListener("click", function () { openDoor() })
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('CloseDoor').addEventListener("click", function () { closeDoor() })
}


function openDoor(){
    document.getElementById('img1').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function closeDoor(){
    document.getElementById('img2').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

In the code exist two problems :

1. I load the page and click the "close door" button and the closed door image appears. If I decide to open the door again by pressing the "open door" button, it wont do it.
2. I load the page and click the "open door" button first. The open door image appears and the if I click on the "close door" button and the image also appears, but I cant repeat the process by re-clicking the "open door" to reopen it.

Comment: For starters, you can't define `window.onload` more than once. The second one overwrites the first. Look into attaching event listeners instead.

Comment: And if you do want to use onload, you can run multiple commands within it. You don't need a separate onload block for each command you want to execute.

Comment: @ADyson technically true, but not a good practice. Other code could easily overwrite it all the same. Better practice to use event listeners.

Comment: @H4desT0uch you already make use of event listeners for the click events. My original comment was to do the same for the window load event itself.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I suppose I was referring to the load event in general, not specifically this way of defining it. The point is that only one event listener is required to implement the functionality shown above. But yes I agree that using `onload` directly is generally not considered to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** In addition to [lucien-dulac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9741030/lucien-dulac)'s point about `window.onload`…

It looks like your two event handlers do a *single thing* to either of two **separate elements**.

- `openDoor()` will only *ever* make `#img1` visible.
- `closeDoor()` will only *ever* make `#img2` visible.

If you want subsequent clicks on `#OpenDoor` or `#CloseDoor` to change the `visibility` style of their respective target elements — `#OpenDoor` controls `#img1`, `#CloseDoor` controls `#img2` — you would need to write a toggle into `openDoor()` and `closeDoor()`.

Something like…

```
function openDoor(){
  var el =  document.getElementById('img1'),
    is_visible = ( el.style.visibility === "visible" );
  if ( is_visible ) {
    el.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! The snippet you showed me, helped me to understand what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are assining a function on the onload event twice. By doing this the first delaration will never be triggered.

It should be more something like :

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('OpenDoor').addEventListener("click", function () { openDoor() })
    document.getElementById('CloseDoor').addEventListener("click", function () { closeDoor() })
}
```

Don't forget to validate the answer if you have what you were looking for

Comment: Note: it's not an obligation to use anonymous function here. You can write `document.getElementById('OpenDoor').addEventListener("click", openDoor)`